# Quickest way to find out which IIS app pool a process is?

Tags: iis, process, application-pools

I have a Windows 2003/IIS6 server with a lot of application pools. In task manager, one of the w3wp.exe processes is using up a lot more resources then the others. Short of stopping/starting each pool one-by-one, is there an easy way to find out which application pool is related to the process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The script iisapp.vbs will list this information for you, it is located in the system32 folder, but you should be able to run it straight from the command line.

Answer (score 6):

use Microsoft Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

You can turn on "command line" as a column and for the W3Wp.exe's it will tell you the app pool.

Comment: Bah, beat me to it :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your apps are ASP.NET:  Use sysinternals Process Explorer, right-click on the process, choose Properties, then click the .NET tab.  You will see the various AppDomains for the .NET process, which for ASP.NET apps typically shows you something like /LM/W3SVC/id/Root/path etc.